# Regex validation bug, it inverts values - javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following Regex:

`const myRegex = new RegExp(/([a-z|\d]){40,78}/gmi)`

I have the following data:

`var data = ['abcdefghijlmnopqrstuvxzabcdefghijlmnopqrstuvxz01', 'abcdefghijlmnopqrstuvxzabcdefghijlmnopqrstuvxz02']`

I do the following:

1st step:

```
data.map(d => myRegex.test(d) && console.log(d, 'ok'))
//abcdefghijlmnopqrstuvxzabcdefghijlmnopqrstuvxz01 ok
```

2nd step:

```
myRegex.test(data[1])
//true
```

After performing steps 1 and 2, I execute them again, but this second time the values are inverted !!! Can someone explain to me why?

Comment: Try https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: It seems portuguese..

Comment: @RobertoCaboni Yes, it seems so, I've edited my comment.

Comment: Sorry guys, I will put in english.